# How can I check if "with" method include some specific string?

Tags: testing, rspec

I'm trying to test that a method receives an argument with an string that includes a substring.

```
class Foo
  def to_test
    called_method “it includes paypal.com“
  end
end
```

I tried with all this differents ways:

```
expect(Foo).to receive(:called_method)).with(include('paypal'))
expect(Foo).to receive(:called_method)).with('paypal')
expect(Foo).to receive(:called_method).with /paypal.com/

subject.to_test
```

But the output is always failing tests as you can see below:

```
expected include('paypal')
got “it includes paypal.com"

expected 'paypal'
got “it includes paypal.com"

expected /paypal/ 
got “it includes paypal.com"
```

Comment: Is called_method on class Foo?

Comment: Which version of Rspec are you using, and can you post the full error message?  both (include('substr')) and /substr/ pass in my tests.